# Radiobuttons in different groups getting enabled on PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

The issue I am having is I have two groups of radio buttons.
When I click "ALL" in either of them the SharePoint DatePicker Control has to be disabled with a showing custom date (as shown in the image). But as you see the first one got enabled when I clicked on the second group of radiobuttons.
Would appreciate if you help me with this issue.

Thanks.

[image]

---

Below are two groups of radio buttons:

//First Group

```
 <asp:RadioButton ID="Rd4Month" Text="All" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="GrpDuration" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="rdgetDateforMonths" />
  <asp:RadioButton ID="Rd1Month" Text="1 month" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="GrpDuration" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="rdgetDateforMonths" />
  <asp:RadioButton ID="Rd2Month" Text="3 month" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="GrpDuration" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="rdgetDateforMonths" />
  <asp:RadioButton ID="Rd3Month" Text="6 month" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="GrpDuration" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="rdgetDateforMonths" />
  <asp:RadioButton ID="Rd5Month" Text="Other" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="GrpDuration" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="rdgetDateforMonths" />
```

//Second Group

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="Rd4BuildMonth" AutoPostBack="True" Text="All" GroupName="GrpBuildDuration" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="rdgetBuildDateforMonths" />
 <asp:RadioButton ID="Rd1BuildMonth" AutoPostBack="True" Text="1 month" GroupName="GrpBuildDuration" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="rdgetBuildDateforMonths" />
 <asp:RadioButton ID="Rd2BuildMonth" AutoPostBack="True" Text="3 month" GroupName="GrpBuildDuration" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="rdgetBuildDateforMonths" />
  <asp:RadioButton ID="Rd3BuildMonth" AutoPostBack="True" Text="6 month" GroupName="GrpBuildDuration" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="rdgetBuildDateforMonths" />
  <asp:RadioButton ID="Rd5BuildMonth" AutoPostBack="True" Text="Other" GroupName="GrpBuildDuration" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="rdgetBuildDateforMonths" />
```

//SharePoint DateTimeControl

```
   <table>
   <tr>
   <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
   <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Start:"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
    <SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="dtcStartDate" runat="server" DateOnly="True" />
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="End:"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
    <SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="dtcEndDate" runat="server" DateOnly="True" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

And the codebehind:

```
  protected void rdgetDateforMonths(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //dtcStartDate.Enabled = true;
       // dtcStartDate.ClearSelection();
       // ViewState["rd4Month"] = "false";
        if (Rd1Month.Checked)
        {
            dtcStartDate.ClearSelection();
            dtcStartDate.Enabled = true;
            dtcStartDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
            //  Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString();
        }

        if (Rd2Month.Checked)
        {
            dtcStartDate.ClearSelection();
            dtcStartDate.Enabled = true;
            dtcStartDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
        }

        if (Rd3Month.Checked)
        {
            dtcStartDate.ClearSelection();
            dtcStartDate.Enabled = true;
            dtcStartDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6);
        }

        if (Rd4Month.Checked)
        {
            dtcStartDate.ClearSelection();
            DateTime value = new DateTime(2012, 04, 01);
            dtcStartDate.SelectedDate = value;
            dtcStartDate.Enabled = false;
         //   ViewState["rd4Month"] = "true";
        }

        if (Rd5Month.Checked)
        {
            dtcStartDate.Enabled = true;
            dtcStartDate.ClearSelection();
        }

    }

 protected void rdgetBuildDateforMonths(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


       // dtcBuildStartDate.ClearSelection();
      //  dtcBuildStartDate.Enabled = true;
     //   ViewState["rd4BuildMonth"] = "false";
        if (Rd1BuildMonth.Checked)
        {
            dtcBuildStartDate.Enabled = true;
            dtcBuildStartDate.ClearSelection();
            dtcBuildStartDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);

        }

        if (Rd2BuildMonth.Checked)
        {
            dtcBuildStartDate.ClearSelection();
            dtcBuildStartDate.Enabled = true;
            dtcBuildStartDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);

        }

        if (Rd3BuildMonth.Checked)
        {
            dtcBuildStartDate.Enabled = true;
            dtcBuildStartDate.ClearSelection();
            dtcBuildStartDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6);

        }

        if (Rd4BuildMonth.Checked)
        {
            dtcBuildStartDate.Enabled = false;
            dtcBuildStartDate.ClearSelection();
            DateTime value = new DateTime(2012, 04, 01);
            dtcBuildStartDate.SelectedDate = value;
            dtcBuildStartDate.Enabled = false;
          //  ViewState["rd4BuildMonth"] = "true";
        }

        if (Rd5BuildMonth.Checked)
        {
            dtcBuildStartDate.Enabled = true;
            dtcBuildStartDate.ClearSelection();

        }
    }

      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //dtcStartDate.MaxDate = System.DateTime.Today;
        dtcBuildStartDate.MaxDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
        dtcStartDate.MaxDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
        dtcEndDate.MaxDate = System.DateTime.Today;
        dtcBuildEndDate.MaxDate = System.DateTime.Today; ;
        lblErrorMsg.Text = "";

        // When the page loads 1st time

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                Rd1Month.Checked = true;
                Rd1BuildMonth.Checked = true;
                dtcEndDate.SelectedDate = System.DateTime.Today; // set end date calendar to today's date
                dtcBuildEndDate.SelectedDate = System.DateTime.Today;
                dtcStartDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
                dtcBuildStartDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblErrorMsg.Text += ex.Message;
            }

        }
    }
```

After I modified the Enable for DateTimeControl to False

```
  <SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="dtcBuildStartDate" runat="server" DateOnly="True" Enabled="False" />
```

[image]

Comment: are you setting them to default on page load? what does your page load look like?

Comment: Just curious, why not use [the RadioButtonList control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist(v=vs.110).aspx)? Seems like it would be more suited to your needs. Also, could you show the markup of your SharePoint datepicker controls?

Comment: I added the Page_Load and also SharePoint DateTimeControl to the above piece of code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the Page_Load method that you just added and reading the comment to my previous post.  It looks like the problem is with the way the share point date time control acts.  You can try adding EnableViewState="true".

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="dtcBuildStartDate" runat="server" DateOnly="True" Enabled="False" EnableViewState="true" />
```

If viewstate is not turned on then every time your page posts back it reloads the default value from the aspx page definition.  This would also affect things like the control's value not being maintained after a postback etc.  If the enableviewstate doesn't work then you could try adding storing the state yourself in ViewState then on each postback you would have to manage this value, but it might get complicated with dealing with changes etc.

You can also try the following on page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //dtcStartDate.MaxDate = System.DateTime.Today;
            dtcBuildStartDate.MaxDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
            dtcStartDate.MaxDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
            dtcEndDate.MaxDate = System.DateTime.Today;
            dtcBuildEndDate.MaxDate = System.DateTime.Today; ;
            lblErrorMsg.Text = "";

            // When the page loads 1st time

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                try
                {
                    Rd1Month.Checked = true;
                    Rd1BuildMonth.Checked = true;
                    dtcEndDate.SelectedDate = System.DateTime.Today; // set end date calendar to today's date
                    dtcBuildEndDate.SelectedDate = System.DateTime.Today;
                    dtcStartDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
                    dtcBuildStartDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblErrorMsg.Text += ex.Message;
                }

            }

            SetDateBoxEnabled();
        }

        private void SetDateboxEnabled()
        {
            if (Rd4BuildMonth.Checked)
            {
                dtcBuildStartDate.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                dtcBuildStartDate.Enabled = true;
            }

            if (Rd4Month.Checked)
            {
                dtcStartDate.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                dtcStartDate.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                try
                {
                    Rd1Month.Checked = true;
                    Rd1BuildMonth.Checked = true;
                    dtcEndDate.SelectedDate = System.DateTime.Today; // set end date calendar to today's date
                    dtcBuildEndDate.SelectedDate = System.DateTime.Today;
                    dtcStartDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
                    dtcBuildStartDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);

Comment: This *does* seem like the most likely culprit. The other thing that occurred to me was that maybe the SharePoint date picker the OP is using doesn't interact with the ViewState (or ViewState is disabled on the control explicitly), and it's declared in the markup as `Enabled="True"`, so its state isn't maintained between PostBacks. Granted, that scenario is a little convoluted =) Occam's Razor and all that.

Comment: @Nick, I tried adding the EnableViewState=true but isn't seem to be helping. For some reason whenever any rdButton of the first group is clicked the Other DateControl gets Disabled as shown in the second image. And its the other way round when I click any rdBtn in the Second group.

Comment: It looks like the enabled is being set by the control before the event handler.  You can try setting it to what it should be on each load by checking the status of the checkboxes each time the page loads.

Comment: @Nick, thanks so much for taking the time to helping me understand and also for the code to resolve the problem. The part to check the status of the radiobuttons was the key on each Page_Load. Thanks again!!!